# Alternative for ForEach loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm working with array where it contains array of array object and I tried with ForEach loop now its working fine but I want to know any way to improvise the performance of my array and combined into key value pair as my final result.

```
 0:
Project: {Division__c: "Mechanical", Owner: {…}, Id: "009921",OwnerId: "005C00000049TRKIA2", …}
TaskList: Array(1)
0:
Case: {Owner: {…},Priority: "Normal", Id: "00118627"}
```

and my code is

```
Project.forEach(wrappedProject => {
                result.push({'label':Project.TaskList.Owner.Name,'value':wrappedProject.TaskList.Owner.Name})        
                Project.TaskList.forEach(Task =>{
                    Task.Case.forEach(task => {
                        console.log('task',task)
                        ownerResult.push({'label':task.Owner.Name,'value':task.Owner.Name})        
                   }); 
                })
           
            });
```

Comment: What exactly is slow right now?

Comment: You should use `for..of` loop.

Comment: @micronyks can you please post the answer here in the for of loop ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @micronyks, how does ```for...of``` improve performance?